# Sorting values in Unique Values widget in QGIS

Tags: qgis, fields-attributes, widget, sorting, qgis-custom-widgets

In QGIS 3.24.3 I have a GeoPackage table containing a text field `"box_id"`. Within its `Layer Properties > Attributes Form` page I have assigned it a *Unique Values* widget type as shown here:

[image]

However, when I subsequently edit the table the widget displays the unique values in a *random* order, as shown here:

[image]

How do I display them in *ascending* order?

A review of the QGIS docs, as well as an internet search, turned up nothing.

Comment: I don't know (and have not investigated) why the values are not sorted when using Unique Values widget type. But a workaround is to use the Value Map widget type and select the option to Load Data From layer and use value and description from your box_id field. You will get a sorted dropdown containing all unique values already present in that field.

Comment: @BenW that's perfect - thanks!  If you want to change your comment to an answer I'd be happy to give you credit, along with the bonus points!

Comment: No worries, done :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using the Unique Values widget type, a workaround is to use the Value Map widget type and select the option to Load Data From Layer. Then, using your kestrel_box_inspections layer, select Value and Description from your box_id field.

[image]

As a result, you will get a sorted dropdown in your attributes form containing all unique values taken from the selected layer and field.

[image]